# How to dynamically select fields from a collection using PyMongo?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo

I have a MongoDb database. There are several collections stored in it. How can I dynamically select fields on the basis of raw input using PyMongo?

Comment: Please have a look at ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and revise you post accordingly. Please make sure the question has not already been asked. The subject should be ideally a question, e.g. "How to dynamically select fields from a collection using PyMongo?". Please also consider adding code snippets of what you have tried so far.

Comment: Next time i will take care of it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient()
client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)

db = client['test-database']

import datetime
post = {"author": "Mike",
         "text": "My first blog post!",
         "tags": ["mongodb", "python", "pymongo"],
         "date": datetime.datetime.utcnow()}

posts = db.posts

post_id = posts.insert_one(post).inserted_id

for item in db.posts.find({},{ "_id": 0, "author": 1}):
    print(item)
```

From this, https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_mongodb_find.asp, We can select any fields.

```
"_id"    : 0, # not select '_id' field
"author" : 1  #     select 'author' field
```